# nodejs error 'Cannot read property 'path' of undefined'

Tags: nodejs

```
router.post('/uploadImage', (request, response, next) => {
    let formidable = require('formidable');
    // parse a file upload
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.uploadDir = `../imagenes/`;
    form.keepExtensions = true;
    form.maxFieldsSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; //10 MB
    form.multiples = true;
    form.parse(request, (err, fields, files) => {
        if (err) {
            response.json({
                result: "failed",
                data: {},
                messege: `Cannot upload images.Error is : ${err}`
            });
        }

        var arrayOfFiles = [];
        if(files[""] instanceof Array) {
            arrayOfFiles = files[""];
        } else {
            arrayOfFiles.push(files[""]);
        }

        if (arrayOfFiles.length > 0) {
            var fileNames = [];
            arrayOfFiles.forEach((eachFile)=> {
                // fileNames.push(eachFile.path)
                fileNames.push(eachFile.path.split('/')[1]);
            });
            response.json({
                result: "ok",
                data: fileNames,
                numberOfImages: fileNames.length,
                messege: "Upload images successfully"
            });
        } else {
            response.json({
                result: "failed",
                data: {},
                numberOfImages: 0,
                messege: "No images to upload !"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: chequea que valor estas colocando en `arrayOfFiles ` y mira `files[""]`

Comment: como podria checkearlo ? con un `console.log(arrayOfFiles )`  ?

Comment: de hecho con un `console.log(arrayOfFiles[0] )`

Comment: no puedo hacerlo , colo  un console log pero solo sale el error que he publicado aqui, ignora el imprimir por consola

Comment: chequea esta linea `arrayOfFiles.push(files[""]);` creo que debe ser algo como `arrayOfFiles.push(files[0]);`

Comment: Mira, el error me dice que esta aqui 
 `fileNames.push(eachFile.path.split('/')[1]);` y que lo que falla es el `path` que no lo reconoce

Comment: Vale el `console.log()` me dice que es `undefined`

Comment: chequea es el `files` ese valor es el que debe tener el fichero

Comment: al poner `console.log('Files = '+files)` me saca esto : `Files = [object Object]`

Comment: entonces tu error es que `arrayOfFiles = files` asi debe ser

Comment: de acuerdo, pero ahora me dice que la funcion `push()`  me da este error = `TypeError: arrayOfFiles.push is not a function`  , causado por esto `arrayOfFiles.push(files[""]);` , pero claro **push()** lo tengo que oner si o si , si no no rellenare mi array

Comment: cambia `arrayOfFiles.push(files[""])` por  `arrayOfFiles = files`

Comment: ahora me devuelve el backend un `codigo 200` de esa peticion ajax, en cambio el `response` a la pagina web es =  ´{
    "result": "failed",
    "data": {},
    "numberOfImages": 0,
    "messege": "No images to upload !"
}´

y en el directorio no se ha subido la foto que lo acabo de comprobar

Answer (score -1):

El problema que tienes es que `files` nunca es un arreglo, siempre [es un objeto](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/blob/d23e5605cdd42963b0c8f5b1961ac088055e39f6/lib/incoming_form.js#L84) donde las llaves son el nombre del campo en donde mandaron el fichero y el valor es un objeto o un arreglo dependiendo si mandaron varios ficheros en el mismo campo desde el cliente.

Este código

```
var arrayOfFiles = [];
if(files[""] instanceof Array) {
    arrayOfFiles = files[""];
} else {
    arrayOfFiles.push(files[""]);
}
```

puede escribirse

```
var arrayOfFiles = Object.keys(files).reduce((curr, key) => {
    const group = files[key]; // Para chequear si es fichero único o arreglo
    if (Array.isArray(group)) {
        curr = curr.concat(group); // Si es arreglo concatenalo al que ya tienes
        // o también [...curr, ...group]
    } else {
        curr.push(group); // Sino agregalo al final
        // o también [...curr, group]
    }
    return curr;
}, []);
```

O aún más simplificado

```
var arrayOfFiles = Object.keys(files)
    .reduce((curr, key) => Array.isArray(files[key])
        ? [...curr, ...files[key]]
        : [...curr, files[key]]
        , []);
```

Eso te generará un arreglo con todos los ficheros de tu request. Tu solución sería

```
router.post('/uploadImage', (request, response, next) => {
    let formidable = require('formidable');
    // parse a file upload
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.uploadDir = `../imagenes/`;
    form.keepExtensions = true;
    form.maxFieldsSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; //10 MB
    form.multiples = true;
    form.parse(request, (err, fields, files) => {
        if (err) {
            response.json({
                result: "failed",
                data: {},
                messege: `Cannot upload images.Error is : ${err}`
            });
        }

        var arrayOfFiles = Object.keys(files)
            .reduce((curr, key) => Array.isArray(files[key])
                ? [...curr, ...files[key]]
                : [...curr, files[key]]
                , []);

        if (arrayOfFiles.length > 0) {
            var fileNames = [];
            arrayOfFiles.forEach((eachFile) => {
                // fileNames.push(eachFile.path)
                fileNames.push(eachFile.path.split('/')[1]);
            });
            response.json({
                result: "ok",
                data: fileNames,
                numberOfImages: fileNames.length,
                messege: "Upload images successfully"
            });
        } else {
            response.json({
                result: "failed",
                data: {},
                numberOfImages: 0,
                messege: "No images to upload !"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: me devuelve el mismo json  =´{
    "result": "failed",
    "data": {},
    "numberOfImages": 0,
    "messege": "No images to upload !"
}´

Comment: puede ser que lo este haciendo mal con el programa postman ?

Comment: @joseangel Yo lo acabo de probar y funciona. Revisa que lo copiaste bien y que estes usando el Postman correctamente

Comment: a ver lo que es el servidor internamente recibe el codigo 200 de que esta bien, pero la respuesta dice q hay un error (el response) , miro mi directorio y no esta subida la foto. En cuanto al postman lo tengo en metodo **POST** , en la seccion **Body** y en el apartado **form-data** subiendo un **File**

Comment: si estas en gnu/linux no olvides dar permiso a la carpeta que va a guardar

Comment: @joseangel Lo siento, no me percaté que había cambiado el path de la carpeta `imagenes`. Respuesta actualizada

Comment: Lo siento, pero sigue sin irme, el directorio ya lo corregi no te preocupes gracias. Creo que es alguna tonteria, algun despiste o algo muy tonto lo que esta fallando pero realmente no se que puede ser. Estoy en Windows @devconcept .

Comment: Por otra parte esto no logro entenderlo : `        var arrayOfFiles = Object.keys(files)
            .reduce((curr, key) => Array.isArray(files[key])
                ? [...curr, ...files[key]]
                : [...curr, files[key]]
                , []);
`

Comment: @joseangel Yo tambien lo probé en Windows. El Postman a veces te resetea los campos de ficheros. Prueba a introducir todos los valores nuevamente. Ese código que no entiendes es exactamente lo mismo que usando `concat` y `push`.  Lee https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_array_literals

Comment: Muchas gracias por la documentacion. Con que opciones  del postman lo has hecho tu ? Las mismas que las mias  que puse arriba ?

Comment: @joseangel probé con 1 campo, varios campos diferentes con 1 fichero cada uno y 2 campos con uno y dos ficheros cada uno.

Comment: @joseangel Prueba usando [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/download/). El POSTMAN a veces te cambia el `content-type` de tu formulario

Comment: como tienes tu el `content-type` ?

Comment: @joseangel Es `multipart/form-data`

Comment: @devconcept que va tampoco me lo sube asi, en la consola del backend me pone que es `codigo:200` pero no se sube, y el response que me da en postman es que no hay ficheros seleccionados para subir

Comment: @joseangel debes debuguear el código

Comment: Y el downvote a que se debe? Yo probé el código y funciona perfectamente. Quizas el OP le dió error por alguna otra causa.